# npm is not installing all files in node_modules folder in vs code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio, compass

npm is not downloading all files in node_modules folder when i run `npm install mongodb`

code is not running and also not throw error and cursor stuck

Comment: You are installing mongodb driver. If you are trying to install dependencies then the command is `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

can you provide error message also
or you should try this command
`npm install mongodb -f`   or

```
npm install mongodb -force
```